# Simple Video Editor for Windows

Tags: windows, video, video-editing

I'm looking for a simple video editor that IS NOT movie maker. I need it be able to:

- Run on Windows 7 or above
- Start Quickly
- Able to crop videos
- Able to Mesh Videos together
- Able to import a variety of video formats (although this is not a must)

Comment: Any budget to name, or unlimited funding? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would check out [Filmora](http://filmora.wondershare.com/video-editor/) by WonderShare. It has a lot of features and still easy to use. It is able to run on Windows 7 and runs quickly for what it does. It can crop videos, mesh them together, and import a large variety of video formats. Currently it's priced at $19 per year or $39 for life but there is a trial version.

[image: Filmora's UI]

Answer (score 2):

A really great software is [Blender](https://www.blender.org/). It is mainly a 3d animation software but it has also a built-in video sequencer. It may be a bit complicated first but when you become use to it, it is a really powerful software. Here is a tutorial how to use it: http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/

Comment: documentation moved to https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/vse/index.html, if "Video Sequence Editor" is what you referred to